# Exception when trying to kill a task

Tags: java

In the below code I'm trying to kill the iTunes process, which is running. But I am getting exception. What I'm missing?

**Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class KillProcess {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASK KILL /F /IM itunes.exe");
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "TASK": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no space between `TASK` and `KILL`. It is `TASKKILL`.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /F /IM itunes.exe");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("taskkill","/F","IM","itunes.exe");
pb = pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

This should also work.